# Inconsistent state in Account Debit - Credit Application Using Kafka Transaction

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

Use Case : 
Account A sends 500 bucks to Account B , We are using a single topic : **"account"** having multiple partitions to record these events

Producer -> 
1.Transaction starts 
2.Account A  BalanceA (-) 500 to topic Account , partition p0 
3.Account B  BalanceB (+) 500 to topic Account , partition p1 
4.Transaction Ends

on Consumer Side we have single stream thread that handle these partition , and update its global state store(Global K Table) accordingly , consumers consuming these partitions consume these message at different poll  and inconsistent state is produced

1.Subtract 500 from Account A in global state store  on some poll
2.consuming some non transnational data from other partitions 
3.Add 500 to Account B in global state store   -- on another poll

In between step 1 & 3, We have inconsistent state in which Account A is debited but Account B is not credited

How can We consume transnational data atomically in application using Low level Kafka Stream API to update its global State Store(Global K Table) in order to avoid inconsistent state at any point of time.

Comment: This video might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2RJQELoM6Y

Answer (score 1):

updating state-store record by record for a transaction may lead to a inconsistent view for a fraction of time, while updating state-store application should write whole transaction atomically (batch commit). Using stream application or consumer there is no way to get transaction start/end markers to perform batch commit.
Using simple consumer in READ_COMMITTED mode you can ask end-offsets(LSO) before poll, buffer all records in temporary map until you hit end-offsets(LSO), and then write temporary map to actual state-store atomically (batch commit/flush). This process will ensure that state-store is consistent and there will be no partial updates in case of transaction.